# E4X select Nodes where descendants can be either A OR B or A && B

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

So I have this XML structure:

```
<Items>
<Item name="aaa">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="1" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
<Item name="bbb">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="2" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
<Item name="ccc">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="1" />
        <ProductRange id="2" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
</Items>
```

Using the following E4X query I get only item "aaa" and item "bbb".

```
trace(   Items.Item.(descendants("ProductRange").@id == "1" || descendants("ProductRange").@id == "2")   );
```

However, I can kind of see why I'm not seeing item "ccc" because it is BOTH id="1" && "2"

So not really sure what the correct query should be here, and even if descendants is the correct technique.

I don't want to end up doing long additional id="1" && id="2" queries either because I have unlimited combinations of these values ("2" && "3", "1" && "2" && "3") etc..

Any thoughts would be most helpful..

Thanks

---

So Patrick solved this with this expression:

```
xml.Item.(descendants('ProductRange').(@id=="1" || @id=="2").length()>0);
```

However, taking this one step further, how would dynamically create the @id values, because this will be a changing query depending on user selections.

Something like this (but this, but this doesn't work):

```
var attributeValues:String = "@id==\"1\" || @id==\"2\" || @id==\"3\" || @id==\"4\"";
xml.Item.(descendants('ProductRange').(attributeValues).length()>0);
```

Any more thoughts Patrick.. anyone?

Thanks

Comment: You should open another question since this one have been answered , an array holding your values can be made and then search into it: http://pastebin.com/vxyVK86V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Or search you can simply do :

```
xml.Item.(descendants('ProductRange').(@id=="1" || @id=="2").length()>0);
```

---

Using a custom filter function you can do your And search that is more complicated than an Or:

```
var xml:XML=<Items>
<Item name="aaa">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="1" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
<Item name="bbb">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="2" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
<Item name="ccc">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="1" />
        <ProductRange id="3" />
        <ProductRange id="2" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
</Items>;

function andSearch(node:XMLList, searchFor:Array) {
    var mask:int = 0;
    var match:int = (1 << searchFor.length ) - 1;
    var fn:Function = function(id:String) {
        var i:int = searchFor.indexOf(id);
        if (i >= 0) {
            mask = mask | (1<<i);
        }
        return mask==match;
    }
    node.(ProductRange.(fn(@id)));
    return mask==match;
}

trace( xml.Item.( andSearch( ProductRanges, ["1", "2"] ) ) );
```

Comment: This is only returning "ccc"... This seems very useful, but am I understanding that this will ONLY return "AND" combinations. I will still need to query for "OR" separately?

Comment: @ukmikeb Yes that was for the And search that is more complicated than the Or, i have add the Or query above.

Comment: Hey Patrick you know what, your OR qury was actually EXACTLY what I needed. 

xml.Item.(descendants('ProductRange').(@id=="1" || @id=="2").length()>0);

My OR query wasn't returning "ccc" but yours is.... many thanks!

Comment: any thoughts on my edit above... need to make the values dynamic, from an array or string?!

Answer (score 0):

This may be messy but bear with me:

```
Items.Item.(
    ( descendants("ProductRange").@id == "1" || descendants("ProductRange").@id == "2" ) ||
    ( descendants("ProductRange").@id == "1" && descendants("ProductRange").@id == "2" )
)
```

Comment: I don't think the boolean logic here is right? can you double check.  How I'm reading this is if (ProductRange.id == 1 or ProductRange.id == 2) as predicate 1, this is true if either of those is true, then it's "ored" again with something that in part includes ProductRange.id==1, if that part is true the first predicate was already true, therefore "orring" it has no affect?

Comment: Thanks for the try... but this still just returns "aaa" and "bbb".
Going to try Patrick's suggestion.