# Dynamic E4X expressions

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, dynamic, e4x

My last Q:
[E4X select Nodes where descendants can be either A OR B or A && B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787607/e4x-select-nodes-where-descendants-can-be-either-a-or-b-or-a-b)
was concerning how to query for multiple attribute values in E4X expressions, which @Patrick answered with this:

```
xml.Item.(descendants('ProductRange').(@id=="1" || @id=="2").length()>0);
```

Now the question is, how do we make the values dynamic using an array or string?

A bit like this, but this DOES NOT work:

```
var attributeValues:String = "@id==\"1\" || @id==\"2\" || @id==\"3\" || @id==\"4\"";
xml.Item.(descendants('ProductRange').(attributeValues).length()>0);
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array holding your values can be made for example and then using an [indexOf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) search to find the id in it :

```
var xml:XML=<Items>
<Item name="aaa">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="1" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
<Item name="bbb">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="2" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
<Item name="ccc">
    <ProductRanges>
        <ProductRange id="1" />
        <ProductRange id="3" />
        <ProductRange id="2" />
    </ProductRanges>
</Item>
</Items>;

// you values filled from whatever source
var valuesToFind:Array=["1","2", "3"]; 

// search if @id exist into your values
// and unsure that there is any node returned
var res:XMLList=xml.Item.(descendants('ProductRange').(valuesToFind.indexOf(@id.toString())>=0).length()>0);
trace(res);
```

Comment: and to confirm, this indexOf technique, won't falsely find the id value "1" in the value "14" ??? Seems to work OK for me.

Comment: indexOf will just search through the array for the value you want, as there is no "14" in your values to find there is no pb.

Comment: was just double checking that IF, you had a node <ProductRange id="14" /> it wouldn't be wrongly found by the search for "1" (because "1" is IN "14")... however it does seem fine, which is great!

Comment: id="14", but array values are only "1", "2", "3" so everything is fine . indexOf will not search inside each string but only for each value.